# Restoring WIndows From Safe Mode

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot, safe-mode

I have a dual boot Laptop with windows 8 and Ubuntu ,
I tried entering safe mode by using the System Configuration but now for some reason when i select windows 8 from the grub boot it just don't boot and freeze , so how can i disable safe mode which seem to be bugged ?

i tried pressing f8 but no luck doing that 
By the way i have struggled to submit this question because of the "Question Quality Filter"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem which occurs when a Linux OS is installed beside a Windows installation. **GRUB**, the [bootloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bootloader) that Linux uses, cannot recognise a Windows installation, and hence on booting a blank screen is shown.

Use the Windows Repair CD, and run startup repair. The problem will be automatically fixed. A fresh Windows bootloader will be written, which recognises GRUB and hence, can dual-boot Linux.

If you do not have the Windows Repair CD, download the ISO image on another computer and make a bootable USB (using, I recommend, *Rufus*).

NOTE that *Safe Mode* has nothing to do with your problem.